# iTunes backup process programmatically on iphone 5

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, windows

I am using iTunes 11 and iPhone 5 on Window XP. I want to create iTunes backup process programmatically in my selected location (not in default location). Can you provide any type of suggestion.

Comment: Can you add a bit more details about what you mean be "programmatically"? Usually the backup automatically triggers when you plug in your phone so I assume you are looking for something else here.

Comment: Well, the default location is easy to find. Why do you want to use the selected location?